# R - cross-referencing variables in functions

Tags: r

I have a frame db given by

```
> A <- c(0,1,2,3,0,1)
> B <-c('NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA')
> C <- c('Fnord', 'Fnord','Applebees','Pumpkin','Applebees','Pumpkin')
> db <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

with the property that db$C[j] = db$C[k] for j != k exactly once.  That is, each row shares a C value with exactly one different row - each row has a unique "C-partner."  I would like to create a function that replaces db$B with the db$A value of its "C-partner."  Ideally, the end result should look like

```
> db
    A    B    C
1   0    1    Fnord
2   1    0    Fnord
3   2    0    Applebees
4   3    1    Pumpkin
5   0    2    Applebees
6   1    3    Pumpkin
.
.
.
```

My attempts at this so far have failed.  Apologies if this has been answered before - my search fu gave me no answers.

One example of what I've tried is

```
db$D <- sapply(db$C, FUN=function(x) {return(sum(db$A %in% subset(db, C="x")))})
db$B <- db$D - db$A
```

but it's not giving what I want.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

EDIT: Added a bit of code for clarity.

Comment: Please show what attempts you have made, even if they failed. It will help us answer your question more easily.

Comment: I can post a bunch of terribly written hack-ey code if you like.  One attempt was to use a bunch of for(j %in% 1:6) and for(k %in% 1:6) loops, which seems pretty inefficient for larger data frames.  It seems better to use something like switch() or identical().  I'm not sure how to use the latter with out using index loops.  Obviously identical(db$C,db$C) isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a dataframe that matches you description:

```
db <- rbind(db, structure(list(A = 2:3, B = c(0L, 3L), C = structure(2:3, .Label = c("Applebees", 
"Fnord", "Fnord2", "Pumpkin"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"), row.names = c("7", "8"), class = "data.frame") )

# Then just merge with itself and remove the cases where the C values are '=='
mdb <- merge(db,db, by="A")
mdb[mdb$C.x != mdb$C.y, c('A', 'C.y', 'C.x')]
   A       C.y       C.x
2  0 Applebees     Fnord
3  0     Fnord Applebees
6  1   Pumpkin     Fnord
7  1     Fnord   Pumpkin
10 2     Fnord Applebees
11 2 Applebees     Fnord
14 3    Fnord2   Pumpkin
15 3   Pumpkin    Fnord2
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works for my purposes, but it DID help me with a somewhat unrelated problem.  Thanks!